# Where are objects created in code behind stored in memory?

Tags: asp.net, .net, memory, client

Say we create a 'DataTable' object from a page's code-behind in ASP.NET. 
Where exactly is this datatable held in memory? Client-side or Server-side? Application pool?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Instances of classes are stored in memory on the server-side, in the managed [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_memory_allocation#Dynamic_memory_allocation) to be specific.

Here's a great article explaing the concepts of in-memory storage of variables and objects:

- [Article: Six important .NET concepts - Section: Stack and Heap](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types#Stack%20and%20Heap)

Answer (score 0):

Server-side, in your server's memory. Be carefull when you load a lot of records to the datatable, it may cause a OutOfMemoryExeption.